# How to call a function that is inside another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple image slider in jQuery && JavaScript. I started to branch out and it more of a personal thing to figure out myself and ran in to this problem. I want to call the function `test` after changing the `var count`'s value. Hopefully that would send out (in this case) the next image.

```
var sc;
var count;

  setInterval(function test(){
      $(".slider #"+count).show("slide",{direction:'right'},500);

      $(".slider #"+count).delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);

      if(count==sc || count > sc || count <= 0) {
        count=1;
      }else{
        count=count + 1;
      }
  }, 6500);

  function slider(){
    sc=$(".slider img").length;
    count= 2;

    $(".slider #1").show("fade", 500);
    $(".slider #1").delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);
}


function prev() {
  count = count - 1;
  test();
}
function next() {
  count = count + 1;
  test();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="slider">
    <img id="1" src="images/Background.JPG"/>
    <img id="2" src="images/Background2.jpeg"/>
    <img id="3" src="images/background2.png"/>
    <img id="4" src="images/profilePicture.jpg"/>
  </div>

  <a href="#" class="left" onclick="prev(); return false;">Previous</a>
  <a href="#" class="right" onclick="next(); return false;">Next</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Don't define it inside another function if you want to call it from outside the function.

Comment: You can't call a function defined in another function from outside said function. Its called scoping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access it from outside the function in which it is defined (the scope in which it was defined), you have to have a reference to it that exists in a scope which is visible to the code in which you desire to access it.

The most common way to do this is to define the function which you want to call from multiple places in a scope which is visible to all places from which you wish to call it.  For example:

```
var count;
function test(){
    //Do stuff
}

function slider(){
    //code
    setInterval(test, 6500);
}

function prev() {
  count = count - 1;
  test();
}

function next() {
  count = count + 1;
  test();
}
```

An alternate method, but a bit unusual, of accomplishing the same thing would be:

```
var intervalFunction;

function slider(){
    //code
    setInterval(intervalFunction = function test(){
        //Do stuff
    }, 6500);
}

function prev() {
  count = count - 1;
  intervalFunction();
}

function next() {
  count = count + 1;
  intervalFunction();
}
```

Comment: Your alternate version won't work because the `test` identifier is scoped to the inside of the `test` function. You could put the assignment inside the function I guess. It'll get re-assigned every time, but it probably won't matter.

Comment: @squint edit: guess you beat me to it haha

I edited the code and I put function test outside but it gives me a undefined function 'test' when I try to click on previous or next? Does the setInterval mess with it's scope?

Comment: @RyanLong Did you put `function test` outside of `function slider`?

Comment: @RyanLong: It isn't specifically `setInterval` that changes the scope of that identifier, but more generally the fact that the named function is used as part of an expression instead of as a function declaration. It's usually called a *named function expression*, and as you noticed, changes the scoping of the function's name. It would be the same if you did `var foo = function bar() {}`. You can use `foo` outside but `bar` must be inside.

Comment: @squint thank you! I understand a little bit more about how to define things and I'll try to get back to it

Comment: sorry my internets slow.. for some reason have to refresh to see new comments (you type a little faster than me haha) @squint I took the function 'test' out of the setInterval ,fixed the syntax on the test function, and rewrote setInterval like 
    
setInterval(test(), 6500);

Comment: @RyanLong: Almost... `setInterval(test, 6500)`. No parens after `test`. Makyen's first solution shows it like that.

Comment: @squint it seems the setInterval also messes with when the function is called upon. I thought it would instantly change and go through function test's code, but it always waits that 6500 before it changes.

Comment: @RyanLong: That's just how it works. It's not invoked until after the first interval. But since you now have a reference to `test`, you can call it manually. `setInterval(test, 6500); test()`

Comment: @squint, Re alternate: Yes, the way I had it originally would not work due to `test` being limited in scope. I have adjusted it such that it would. In that alternate case there is no need to leave the `test` identifier there (other than it makes it easier for us humans to write about it).

Comment: @squint Makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about [closures in JavaScript?](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) Is this what you mean about a function within a function?

```
  function slider(){
    sc=$(".slider img").length;
    count= 2;

    $(".slider #1").show("fade", 500);
    $(".slider #1").delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);
    return function(){return var += count }
```